Visual Studio 2022 hangs on loading project
I'm opening MS VS Pro 2022 (64-bit) - Version 17.7.7 on my dev box, and I get a pop up box saying "Updating parent of project 2 of 11":  xxx.xxxxx.xxxx (the project name.)
The Git Changes tab displays an error message at the top:  "Index was outside the bounds of the array."
And it hangs there.  (I've been working on this project for years, and it's never done this before.)  Cancel button doesn't work, all I can do is force VS closed.
Any suggestions as to cause or how to fix?


https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Index-outside-bounds-when-switching-bran/10563259

Try resetting the Git repository associated with the project by running the following commands in the root directory of the project:
git reset --hard HEAD 
git clean -xdf

Afterward, reopen the solution in Visual Studio and see if the issue persists.
